# How to test a function that watches a file in a goroutine

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, go

I have a function that watches certian file via fsnotify and calls a callback when the file changes. If the callback returns false, the watching is ended:

```
import (
    "github.com/golang/glog"
    "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify"
)

type WatcherFunc func(err error) bool

func WatchFileChanges(filename string, watcherFunc WatcherFunc) {
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()

    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorf("Got error creating watcher %s", err)
    }

    defer watcher.Close()

    done := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case event := <-watcher.Events:
                glog.Infof("inotify event %s", event)

                if event.Op&fsnotify.Write == fsnotify.Write {
                    glog.Infof("modified file %s, calling watcher func", event.Name)

                    if !watcherFunc(nil) {
                        close(done)
                    }
                }

            case err := <-watcher.Errors:
                glog.Errorf("Got error watching %s, calling watcher func", err)

                if !watcherFunc(err) {
                    close(done)
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    glog.Infof("Start watching file %s", filename)

    err = watcher.Add(filename)

    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorf("Got error adding watcher %s", err)
    }
    <-done
}
```

Then I thought it would be nice to have a test for that, so I started out with a simple test case:

```
import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestStuff(t *testing.T) {
    tmpfile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "test")

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal("Failed to create tmp file")
    }

    defer os.Remove(tmpfile.Name())

    watcherFunc := func (err error) bool {
        return false
    }

    WatchFileChanges(tmpfile.Name(), watcherFunc)
}
```

What I wanted do to here is to do a few modifications to the file, collect the events in an array, return then `false` from the `watcherFunc` and then assert on the array. The thing is, of course the test just hangs and waits for events, as the goroutine was started.

Is there any way how I can test a function like this, like … starting a different thread (?) that updates/modifies the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way how I can test a function like this, like … starting a different thread (?) that updates/modifies the file?

Of course... start a goroutine that does the updates you want.

```
func TestStuff(t *testing.T) {
    tmpfile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "test")

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal("Failed to create tmp file")
    }

    defer os.Remove(tmpfile.Name())

    watcherFunc := func (err error) bool {
        return false
    }
    go func() {
        // Do updates here
    }()

    WatchFileChanges(tmpfile.Name(), watcherFunc)
}
```

Comment: Your goroutine is never called, that's a compiler error for go 1.7.